# Writing a file from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, linux-networking

I'm running `R` locally (Windows 10) while connected to a VPN. During an `R` session, I'm generating several files that I can write to a connected Windows server by using the file path

```
write.csv([r-obj], "//[servername]/path/to/file.csv")
```

where `r-obj` is the `R` object I'm writing.

Because of ePHI reasons, we've stood up a Redhat AWS AMI inside of our VPC and I have installed `RStudio Server v1.1.463` on that AMI, installed git, pulled the repo, and am running the same code via `RStudio Server` that I was using locally. This AMI is connected to the same network as our VPN and I can `ping [servername]` successfully while I am ssh'd into the Redhat AMI. However, I can't use the above filepath to write the generated files; I keep getting a standard `R` `cannot open the connection` error which suggests that the filepath is incorrect.

Based on some responses I've found here and elsewhere (through Googling), I tried using `samba` via

```
sudo yum install samba
```

and updating the filepath to be

```
smb://[servername]/path/to/file.csv
```

and also

```
smb://[myusername:mypassword]@servername/path/to/file.csv
```

but I keep getting the same error.

I tried "mounting" the share as

```
sudo yum install cifs
sudo mount -t cifs //[servername/path /mnt -o user=[myusername]
```

then adding `mypassword` when prompted but still no luck.

I'm not generally a Linux user and I don't have much knowledge base with how to solve the filepath issue on my own. I've tried some of the more simple potential solutions I've found (see above). I haven't found anything on SF specific to this problem, mostly just questions related to copying files back and forth.

Am I going about this the right way? Can I write from Linux to Windows successfully? I suspect I can and I suspect there's a simple thing that I'm missing. *Please note that I'm not trying to manually copy a file but I have code that should be able to write directly to a file without any additional input.*

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would setup the SMB folder on the Linux box and have the csv files  there.

All you would have to do is add some config to /etc/samba/smb.conf and restart the service, which is pretty straightforward.

From the Windows box, you can access it \IP Address\Share.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but this doesn't help with my question. We have a number of other internal users that have the `servername` mapped locally and all files need to be written there as there are already several months worth of data and other output stored in `servername`.

Comment: And the firewall on the server is open (CIFS uses UDP ports 137 and 138, and TCP ports 139 and 445)?  The file path you have looks correct.

Comment: Also I've had issues with this different SMB versions being used.

Answer (score 0):

- SMB is one way to do it but sometimes can be painful dealing with different versions, permissions, etc.
- Other option is to upload your files to s3 and then pull to EC2 instance but since you have VPN tunnel not really optimal.
- Another and probably my favorite is to provision EFS share on AWS, mount it on your instance and transfer files via NFS from your windows machines.